# How to obtain an array of json back from req.body in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, body-parser, stringify

I want to post an array of json to node js. I did the same using ajax post method.On the server side i tried to access the same with req.body. But the result is in the form of string. So i am not able to iterate over the json array elements one by one.How can I do this?JSON.parse or stringyfy everything is displaying as object .This is what obtained in the req.body

```
      req.body: '[{"img_id":"img_1","name":"abc","source":"img/Icon_ABc.
  png"},{"img_id":"img_0","name":"flower","source":"img/Icon_flower.png"}, 
  {"img_id":"img_5","name":"panda","source":"img/Icon_panda.png"
  }]'
```

the post method i used is ajax.

```
     Dataform.append("finalAray",JSON.stringify(finalArray))
 $.ajax({
    url: '/api/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: Dataform,

    success: function(data){
       //................
    },
    error: function(exception){
        alert('error:'+exception);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to obtain the array from req.body,I have send the JSON array as a query parameter in the url of ajax post. So i got the array as string in the req.query in the server. Then I parsed it and was able to iterate.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/upload/?finalArray='+JSON.stringify(finalArray),
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: fileform,
     success: function(data){
      // ........
    },
    error: function(exception){
        alert('error:'+exception);
    }
});
```

In the server ,

```
 array=req.query.finalArray;
 JSON.parse(array);
 array.forEach(function(element,index){
        console.log(element);
        console.log(index);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for testing and the updates. I had assumed you were posting JSON only, whereas you're posting form data, which includes JSON.

I believe the best approach in this case is to use the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) module to parse the uploaded data like below:

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer();

app.use(express.static("./"));


app.post('/', upload.any(), function(req,res){
    console.log('Received files from client: ', req.files);
    console.log('Received form data from client: ', req.body);

    console.log('Iterating array:');
    let array = JSON.parse(req.body.finalAray);
    array.forEach((element, index) => {
        console.log(`Element at [${index}]: ${element}`)
    });
    res.json( { "status": "ok" } );
})


app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**client**

```
{     
Dataform.append("finalAray",JSON.stringify(finalArray))
 $.ajax({
    url: '/api/upload/',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: Dataform,

    success: function(data){
       //................
    },
    error: function(exception){
        alert('error:'+exception);
    }
});
```

Comment: but am not getting the values in iteration.The req.body is obtained as shown in the question.On iterating through it i am getting error as req.body.for each is not a function... @Terry

Comment: Hey, @Aparna, thank you very much for trying my code! Could you do a console.log(req.body) in the server and see what it shows? Thanks!

Comment: '[{"img_id":"img_1","name":"abc","source":"img/Icon_ABc.
  png"},{"img_id":"img_0","name":"flower","source":"img/Icon_flower.png"}, 
  {"img_id":"img_5","name":"panda","source":"img/Icon_panda.png"
  }]'  @Terry -- the req.body is wrapped in single quotes. so it is a string.So I cant iterate.

Comment: Ihave edited question with my ajax post calL.content type is set false .When i gave content type as application/json the files appended along with the json in formData object is not uploaded.@Terry

Comment: thank you for your answer. But when i give req.body.forEach (function(element,index){}), it throws error as " TypeError: req.body.forEach is not a function "...@Terry

Comment: I used query in the req  to pass the json instead of body. It is working. I dont know whether it is the correct way of implementation. But its is solving my issue. Thank you for trying this code.@Terry..I will edit my question with my new code. Pls do check